# A good introduction into realizing 3D graphics with vectors and matrices without mattering a programming language or directx/opengl

Tags: vector, matrix, 3d

I'm starting in 3D programming.

So I learn about vectors, matrices and all that stuff.

The question I lack is knowing about how all this stuff generates a 3D image.

What I need is an introduction to vectors, matrices and how these can be combined to make i.e. a 3D landscape. Let's say, I need it shown and explained just as you write it on the paper.

Sadly, I cannot find a real good with Google... what I found are just code samples for OpenGL written in C++ with no good comments about what each line does and no information in depth about vectors and matrices.

Many thanks and best wishes,
Joern.

Comment: +1 For somebody who starts with 3D programming at the right point (the maths and the pipeline).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can heartily recommend this book by Peter Shirley:

[http://www.amazon.com/Fundamentals-Computer-Graphics-Peter-Shirley/dp/1568814690/ref=pd_sim_b_14](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1568814690)